# Given KNOWNFOLDERID or its GUID get the associated icon under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Looking for a way to get the icon associated with a desktop shortcut using C++, when all I have is its GUID - something like {82A74AEB-AEB4-465C-A014-D097EE346D63} or its KNOWNFOLDERID

Comment: If you have the known folder ID, you can use `SHGetKnownFolderIDList` to get a PIDL and then `SHGetFileInfo` to get the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, based on the [IShellItemImageFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory) interface that exists since Windows Vista:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
{
    CComPtr<IKnownFolderManager> mgr;
    if (SUCCEEDED(mgr.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_KnownFolderManager)))
    {
        CComPtr<IKnownFolder> folder;
        if (SUCCEEDED(mgr->GetFolder(FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder, &folder)))
        {
            CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
            // I pass 0 for flags here, but mileage may differ
            if (SUCCEEDED(folder->GetIDList(0, &pidl)))
            {
                CComPtr<IShellItemImageFactory> factory;
                if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))))
                {
                    // you can vary size and SIIGBF flags
                    HBITMAP bmp = nullptr;
                    SIZE size = { 256, 256 };
                    if (SUCCEEDED(factory->GetImage(size, SIIGBF_ICONONLY, &bmp)))
                    {
                        // etc...
                        DeleteObject(bmp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
```

And there is even a better way using the [SHCreateItemInKnownFolder function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateiteminknownfolder):

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
{
    CComPtr<IShellItemImageFactory> factory;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder, 0, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))))
    {
        // you can vary size and SIIGBF flags
        HBITMAP bmp = nullptr;
        SIZE size = { 256, 256 };
        if (SUCCEEDED(factory->GetImage(size, SIIGBF_ICONONLY, &bmp)))
        {
            // etc...
            DeleteObject(bmp);
        }
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
```

Note this will get you the icon as an HBITMAP.

Comment: I'm curious if `SHGetItemFromObject()` would work, instead of having to use `GetIDList()`+`SHCreateItemFromIDList()`? `SHGetItemFromObject(folder, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))`  Or maybe even from `IKnownFolder::GetShellItem()` instead? `folder->GetShellItem(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))`

Comment: Thank you, that does the job quite nicely.
What would be different to use GUID instead? For some instances, it would be easier to work with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - SHGetItemFromObject(knownfolder, imageFactory) doesn't work,and I wasn't able to get IShellItemImageFactory from an IShellItem I tried various BHID combinations (initially I wanted to use that instead of pidls). Note the IShellItemImageFactory doc mentions only a couple of methods, which allowed me to find a better way :-)

Comment: @Stacker - not sure what you mean? FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder is already a guid

Comment: I am trying to use a GUID string for a virtual folder, such as {82A74AEB-AEB4-465C-A014-D097EE346D63}, rather than what I am thinking of a FOLDERID... macro

Comment: @Stacker - you can use CLSIDFromString or IIDFromString to convert to a guid.

Comment: Neither of the above work for me and I am to new to the !@^&* markdown to be able to produce a readable code extract :-(
Looked over the tutorial several times and got nowhere.
At this point , I can get a visible 16x16 icon for all but 'This PC'

Comment: @Stacker - not sure what's your problem exactly. You can use a tool such as paste.bin to  put sample code on the internet